# How to print several match in the same line with awk

Tags: text-processing, awk

Hi have a tabular file (separator =`\t`) `A.txt` :

```
205 toto patho
207 tata benign
208 titi likely_patho
```

and `B.txt`:

```
210 lolo patho
211 lala benign
212 lili benign
```

And I would like to have a file that print the value of the second column if the third column are "patho" or "likely_patho". With this example, we have :

```
A toto;titi
B lolo
```

In order to do that, I've done :

```
for bla in *.txt; do
r="$(basename -s ".txt" $bla)"
awk -v filename=$r '($3=="patho" || $3=="likely_patho") {print filename"\t"$2}' $bla >> result.txt ;
done
```

But this code give me one line per match in the event that a file contain several match (like `A.txt`) :

```
A toto
A titi
B lolo
```

How can I have the proper output ? Thanks

Comment: Please [edit] your question to add a 3rd input file that has no patho or likely_patho values to the example so we can see what should be output for that case (no file name? a file name on it's own? something else?). Also tell us what the output should be if an input file was empty.

Answer (score 2):

Using any awk:

```
$ cat tst.awk
BEGIN {
    split(t,tmp)
    for ( i in tmp ) {
        tgts[tmp[i]]
    }
    FS = OFS = "\t"
}
FNR == 1 {
    fname = FILENAME
    sub(/\.[^.]*$/,"",fname)
}
$3 in tgts {
    hits[fname] = (fname in hits ? hits[fname] ";" : "") $2
}
END {
    for ( fname in hits ) {
        print fname, hits[fname]
    }
}
```

```
$ awk -v t='patho likely_patho' -f tst.awk *.txt
A       toto;titi
B       lolo
```

Comment: Note that this answer will store most of the output in one array. It will consume a huge amount of memory for a huge output list.

Answer (score 1):

Try :

```
awk '  FNR==1 {  f=FILENAME;
                 sub(/\.[^.]*$/,"",f);
                 printf "%s%s\t",aline,f;
                 aline="\n";
                 s=""
       }
       ($3=="patho" || $3=="likely_patho"){
                 printf "%s%s",s,$2;
                 s="; "
       }
       END{print ""}
    ' ./*.txt
```

Answer (score 0):

try (can be one lined)

```
awk -v filename="$r" 'BEGIN { string=filename "\t" }
          ($3=="patho" || $3=="likely_patho") {printf string $2; string=";" }
          END { printf "\n" } ' $bla >> result.txt ;
```

I use `string` as a prefix, it will print filename first, then semicolon after.

You need to add final newline.

Comment: Quote your shell variables, see https://mywiki.wooledge.org/Quotes, and always do `printf "%s", $<anything>` instead of `printf $<anything>` for any input data as the latter will fail when the input contains printf formatting characters like `%s`. Also, `print ""` is better than `printf "\n"` as the former uses whatever value `ORS` has while the latter hard-codes the value you hope/assume that `ORS` has. This approach requires a surrounding shell loop, though, which is slow and unnecessary.

Answer (score 0):

```bash
grep -HoP '[^\t]+(?=\t(?:likely_)?patho$)' -- *?.txt|
sed 's/\.[^.]*:/\t/'|
awk -F '\t' '
NR==1||prev!=$1{
  printf "%s%s", sep, $0
  prev=$1;sep=ORS
  next 
}
{ printf ";%s", $2 }
END {print ""}'
```

---

```
A   toto;titi
B   lolo
```

Answer (score 0):

Using perl (with extra linefeeds for readability):

```
$ perl -MFile::Basename -F'\t' -le '
$f = fileparse($ARGV, qw(.txt)) if $. == 1;
if ($F[2] =~ /^(likely_)?patho$/) {
  push @{ $files{$f} }, $F[1]
};
close(ARGV) if eof;   # close each input file and reset the line counter $. at eof

END {
  foreach (sort keys %files) {
    print "$_\t", join(";",@{ $files{$_} })
  }
}' A.txt B.txt
A       toto;titi
B       lolo
```

- `-MFile::Basename` tells perl to load the [File::Basename](https://perldoc.perl.org/File::Basename) module. This is a core perl module and is included with perl.
- `-F` sets the field separator (tab) and also enables both perl's `-a` auto-split mode (splits each input line into an array called `@F`, similar to awk), and perl's `-n` option to iterate over its input (behaves similarly to both `sed -n` and `awk`).
- `-l` enables automatic processing of line-endings (`\n` by default).  In short, it removes newline characters from the end of each input line (using perl's `chomp()` function) and adds them to the end of every `print` statement.
- All perl command-line options are documented in `man perlrun`.

The script iterates over each input line and, whenever it finds a match in the third field (`$F[2]` - perl array indices start from zero) it adds the second field to a Hash-of-Arrays (HoA) called `%files`.  This is a hash (associative array) where the key is the base filename and the value is an array of 2nd-field strings.  See the man pages for `perldata`, `perllol`, and `perldsc` for more information about perl data structures.

When all the input has been read and processed, it output the data in the requested format, sorted by filename.

---

NOTE: The `... if $. == 1;` in conjunction with the `close(ARGV) if eof` line ensures that the base filename is only extracted on the first line of each new file.  This isn't required, just a minor optimisation  that would only be beneficial if you have very large input files. If you prefer a slightly shorter one-liner or if performance isn't an issue, delete the `close(ARGV) ...` line and the `if $. == 1` conditional.